# Can I search over SE using SE API if I have only a username?

Tags: discussion, api-v2

How do I can find someone's userid if I have only their username?

For example, my real username is: `Zagorulkin Dmitry`

My Stack Overflow userid is: `1321404`

Are there any API methods for this kind of task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find `user_id`(s) for a username, use the `inname` parameter of [the `/users` query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users).
You will have to repeat this query call for [every Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) that you are interested in.  For example:

- [/users?inname=Zagorulkin&site=stackoverflow&filter=!6Xcz2tYayQsZ1](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users?inname=Zagorulkin&site=stackoverflow&filter=!6Xcz2tYayQsZ1)
- [/users?inname=Zagorulkin&site=programmers.stackexchange&filter=!6Xcz2tYayQsZ1](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users?inname=Zagorulkin&site=programmers.stackexchange&filter=!6Xcz2tYayQsZ1)

If you only want the `user_id`, [create a filter to that effect](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters). For those two example queries, I used a filter to return just the `user_id` and the `account_id`; resulting in:

```
{"items":[{"user_id":1321404,"account_id":1390443}],"quota_remaining":263,"quota_max":300,"has_more":false}
```

and

```
{"items":[{"user_id":57385,"account_id":1390443}],"quota_remaining":262,"quota_max":300,"has_more":false}
```

respectively.

---

The `account_id` is useful, because once you know it, you can use
[`/users/{accountId}/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) to get all of the user's associated account info.